# Flutter : Show properties Widget without Hover the widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm now it's very basic question but i want know it's possible show property widget without hover the widget or it have button combination ?
[image: hover]

It's same like if i want add new widget , i only click the widget and press `Ctrl + .`
[image: card2]

Thank's

Comment: You can always ctrl + click

Comment: You can click the widget and press `Cntrl + Q` on Windows or `Cmd + F1` on Mac

Comment: @SiddharthPatankar not work for me , it's opened another menu

Comment: By click the widget I meant you need to move the cursor into the widget line. Do not hold down the mouse click.